# Styling MenuItem not working as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a menu.

Here is the xaml for creating this menu :

```
<Menu Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ParentButtons}" >

    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>

    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Right">
                                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Padding="2">
                                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                                </Canvas>
                                                <!--<Rectangle Fill="#FFD7D7D7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>-->
                                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Border>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FF707070"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>

                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>

    <Menu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Design_Master_Buttons}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Design_Master_Buttons1}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Path Data="{Binding ImageData}" 
                      Stretch="Uniform" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TransformGroup.Children>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                            </TransformGroup.Children>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Path.RenderTransform>

                    <Path.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding MouseOverColor}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Path.Resources>

                </Path>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Resources>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemTemplate>

</Menu>
```

But I have got 1 problem:

When I mouseOver Path (It's working good):

[image]

When I mouseOver MenuItem (It's not working as expected) :

[image]

Comment: And what kind of behavior should be in the second case?

Comment: Behavior in second Case should be : When I mouseover MenuItem, the Background of path should change as shown in first image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : In my case stackpanel as AncestorType is not worked so i used Menuitem.

```
            <StackPanel>
                   <Path x:Name="PathData" Data="M 0 0 L 0 5 L 5 5 Z" Stretch="Uniform" Width="32" Height="32"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                        <Path.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Path.Style>
                    </Path>
                </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Yes, DataTrigger does the trick. Thank you for helping me again and again.

Answer (score 2):

Your Path resource is not correct replace it by :

```
        <Path.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel,AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" >
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding MouseOverColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Path.Resources>
```

And add `Background="#01000000"` to the StackPanel, it will be able to detect IsMouseOver property.

And now it will works.
Regards.

Comment: Good one. But more perfect answer is given by Heena Patil. So, I have marked it as accepted answer. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: +1 because our appraoch is same but stackpanel  as AncestorType is not worked in my case.